# Entity framework,create app that works with 2 databases types (Firebird and Mysql)

Tags: mysql, entity-framework, postgresql, firebird

I'm using Firebird SQL for my app (windows app).I want to access data also from web (ASP CORE) but I didn't find reasonable Firebird hosting but lot of MySql.If I want the win app to make it working with both database type would be hard with Entity framework?
now app is written with ADO.NET Framewok 3.5 (no Linq)
Postgres is another option
thanks!

Comment: Ticket to add EF Core support: http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-663

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With an ASP.NET Core application you will need to use the Entity Framework Core and you can not use Entity Framework 5. Indeed

- Entity Framework Core is built on the top of .NET Core
- Entity Framework 5 is build on the top of .NET

These are 2 completely different frameworks.

Now we can check what are the EF Core's supported database providers here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/providers/ for example:

- SQL Server is officially supported by ASP.NET team
- MySQL is supported by the community
- PostgreSQL is supported by the community
- (this list is not exhaustive)

Unfortunately there is nothing about Firebird SQL so you can not use it.

**Solution 1** is to write your ASP.NET Core code in order to use Entity Framework Core and you can rewrite your Windows App code in order to use Entity Framework but it's like writing the same code in 2 different frameworks. Also you must keep in mind that Entity Framework Core is currently under development and it will evolve. The roadmap is here https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/wiki/Roadmap

**Solution 2** would be not to use ASP.NET Core but the ASP.NET 4.6 so that you can use Entity Framework (only one code to maintain is always better) for your Web app and your Windows app. Choose carefully ;)

Answer (score 1):

this is now possible, I just released the provider for Firebird.

You can find it here and on NuGet.

https://github.com/souchprod/SouchProd.EntityFrameworkCore.Firebird

Comment: Hi.This is great.but just one clarification: your version it is different from that http://tracker.firebirdsql.org/browse/DNET-663? Thanks

Comment: Hi, no, that's mine. Still in pre-release and contain a few issues, but updated & better everyday.